# Java perform crc check (divide bytearray by bytearray)

Tags: java, udp, arrays, crc, crc16

I generated a `CRC` integer over a byte array and converted it also to 4 bytes array. I used [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/51data/CRC16CCITT.java.html) class for CRC16 which uses generator polynomial = `0x1021;` which means `1 + x + x^5 + x^12 + x^16`
I send my byte array and the `CRC` over `UDP` to the server. On server side I like to check if the byte array was properly transmitted. As I understand it I can just divide the data-array concatenated with crc-array by the generator polynomial. Did I understood that right? And how to perform the `data+crc` division by generator polynomial in Java?

I've seen solutions that just generate the crc code again over the data and compare whether resulted crc codes are the same, but this is'n maybe the thing crc-codes are made for.

Comment: Recalculating the CRC and comparing is the simplest thing to do.

Comment: Incidentally your check is unnecessary since UDP does guarantee the byte[] will be the same as sent as UDP performs it's own check using a checksum before delivering the datagram up.

Comment: it's more for educational reasons then a really use case, but would be nice if you have a reference to this statement ;)

Comment: sure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol you can follow the links in there if you want something more "official"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRC is designed that you simply repeat the CRC computation, but with the CRC bytes appended to the data bytes. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#CRCs_and_data_integrity):

> The validity of a received message can easily be verified by performing the above 
>   calculation again, this time with the check value added instead of zeroes. The remainder
>   should equal zero if there are no detectable errors.

Comment: That only works if the CRC does not have pre or post processing, which most do.  The common approach is to do what you'd do with any check algorithm, which is compute it on just the received message and compare that to the received check value.

Comment: as my code does modification after calculating checksum [crc &= 0xffff;] I need to do it the way you said but accept teh answer above.

Comment: @MarkAdler If the CRC has pre or post processing, how can it be a useful check? My understanding of the point of these types of checks (CRC, parity) is that you simply compute it for the entire received message (including check bits) and make sure that the result is 0.

Comment: It is a useful check because you can check it!  If a deterministic algorithm of any kind, which includes CRCs, produces a check value on a message, then that same check value should be produced by the same algorithm on the same message at the other end.  If it doesn't, then either the message or the check value got corrupted.